# web.show_document uses different base url when used from java webstart

Tags: base-url

Forms 12.2.1.4. Using web.show_document I see different behavior when running the Forms using Java Plugin (JPI) or using Java Webstart (JWS).
Same form, when run  using JPI, web.show_document tries to open: http://server:port/forms/ + (uri you send in web.show_document ('uri').
That same form, when run using JWS, tries to open: http://server:port/forms/java/ + (uri you send in web.show_document('uri')
So:
1.- JWS uses as base url http://server:port/forms/java, while JPI http://server:port/forms/
Do you know the reason? I have a testcase and reproduce internally....I see no differences in configuration between JPI and JWS config.
2.- Another option to solve this could be use a different web.show_document call depending on wheter form is being run using JPI or JWS..... Is there a way to check at runtime if forms is being run using JWS or JPI?
I don't see it possible using get_application_property().

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below code solved my problem:
WEB.SHOW_DOCUMENT('/'||:block3.item4);